# Percentage of $M$ picks (with replacement) that are unique out of $N$ unique choices

Tags: probability, statistics

I have $N$ distinct objects to choose from. I can make $M$ choices with replacement.

I would like to figure out the percentage of the $M$ choices that are distinct. We know that the probability of one of the distinct $N$ objects not being chosen in $M$ choices is
$$
\left( \frac{N-1}{N} \right)^M
$$
So the probability that this distinct object is chosen in $M$ choices is the complement
$$
1 - \left( \frac{N-1}{N} \right)^M
$$

Apparently, this probability (times 100%) is also the percentage of the $M$ choices that are distinct. I'm having trouble making the connection on why the probability that a distinct object is chosen 1 or more times among $M$ choices is equal to the percentage of distinct objects in $M$ choices. It seems to be somewhat intuitive, but is there a mathematical justification for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the items be $a_1,...,a_N$.  Let $X_i$ be $1$ if $a_i$ is chosen at least once; and $0$ otherwise.  So $E[X_i]$ is just the probability that $X_i$ is chosen at least once. This probability is the same for each $i$; so let's call the probability $p$.

Then the number of distinct items chosen is $\sum X_i$.  And the expected value of this sum is just $M\cdot p$, by linearity of expectation.

So the expected proportion of objects chosen is $\frac{M\cdot p}{M}=p$.